# PHP Exclude particular directories from being included in Zip

Tags: php

I have a particular directory called 'customers' that contains various directories. One of the directories is called uploads. Basically where users update their content. This folder contains hundreds of pictures.

What I want is that all the files in this particular directory is added to a zip file except the 'uploads' directory which is backed up separately.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
$zipFolderExclude = 'customers/uploads/*.*';

// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
// open archive
if ($zip->open($zipName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive");
}
// initialize an iterator
// pass it the directory to be processed
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($zipFolder));
// iterate over the directory
// add each file found to the archive
foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    if(!is_dir($zipFolderExclude) ) {
        $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
        echo $key . '<br/>';
    }
}
// close and save archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive created successfully.";
```

The above code is zipping all files. I'm not sure what to do in this particular code:

```
if(!is_dir($zipFolderExclude) ) {
            $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
            echo $key . '<br/>';
        }
```

How can I exclude the uploads directory from the zip, please?

Comment: perhaps `if ($value != $zipFolderToExclude)` instead? Right now you're checking if your zip folder is a folder (duh, it is...) and then merilly adding it to your zip.

Comment: @MarcB - I tried your solution. It didn't work.

Comment: Maybe useful for someone: to exclude some folder make something like this

`foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
 if (strpos(realpath($key), 'customers/uploads') !== false) continue;
 
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
    echo $key . '<br/>';
}`

Answer (score 1):

Since ZipArchive does not explicitly support exclusions (of some directories), you may apply two strategies:

- Strategy 1: use ZipArchive::addGlob (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addglob.php) to filter in only desired directories. Optionally use ZipArchive::addPattern(pattern) for fine tuning included filenames within the directory.
- Strategy 2: include all directories into ZipArchive and then delete unwanted directory with ZipArchive::deleteIndex(index) - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.deleteindex.php. Simple, but may eat up memory depending on the size of unwanted directories.

Comment: Yes, but since this particular link `$zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");` is adding the file recursively, if the directory matches folder can't it be excluded?